# Xcode 7 beta 2 continuously crashing

Tags: c++, xcode, crash, osx-yosemite

I am developing a C++ project with Xcode.

My Xcode keeps crashing out of nowhere. It does so often that it is nearly impossible to work at all. I have been using Xcode 6 until now. Since it kept crashing, I just thought I would format everything. I did a clean install of Yosemite and then downloaded Xcode 7 beta 2 from the official Apple Developer page. I installed it on my clean system, then pulled my repo and tried to work. Still the same problem.

Here is the log of the crash:

http://pastebin.com/t4gMWa95

I have looked around SO and many answers suggested that this could be related to source control. However, I tried to disable source control from my settings and still it crashes as often as before.

Anyone can give me an idea on what is going on? This is frustrating...!

Comment: I am having the same problem. From what I can tell, it is a product of string overflow in the error output. For me it seems to be happening because accumulated class names (including classes specifying traits) are very long. To some extent, setting -ferror-limit=1 helps, but I still get single errors that are too long sometimes. It seems that there is a length where XCode error display breaks (you get a giant text block) and then another length where XCode just straight up crashes (no information provided).

Comment: Xcode 7b3 is now consistently crashing at:
Dispatch queue: shared-compile-command-queue :: NSOperation 0x7ff3dcf672f0 (QOS: UTILITY) 
1   libclang.dylib 0x0000000112522bd7 llvm::report_fatal_error(llvm::Twine const&, bool) + 343
2   0x0000000112522a79 llvm::report_fatal_error(char const*, bool) + 41
3   0x0000000110b26a89 llvm::BitstreamCursor::Read(unsigned int) + 265
4   0x0000000110b26aae llvm::BitstreamCursor::SkipBlock() + 30
5   0x0000000110b2626e clang::serialized_diags::SerializedDiagnosticReader::readDiagnosticBlock(llvm::BitstreamCursor&) + 414
But it's unclear precisely why.

Comment: Apple's XCode team is now working on the problem, having verified reproducible conditions. Issue #21896690 in Apple's bug reporter. I'll update the question with details once they update the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm the crash is in `clang::DiagnosticRenderer::emitDiagnostic` which presumably is redering errors and warnings. Could there be something odd about your warnings? Or something that is echoed in warnings classnames, scource file names, paths to source files?  Does it happen when there is so little code as to have no or few diagnostics? But first - make a new XCode project and add your source to that, see if the new one works better.

Comment: What does it mean, something echoed in warnings?

Comment: I tried to compile the whole project via command line. Indeed, I get 11 warnings, all of the same nature: extraneous template parameter list in template specialization. Not so scary, I just added a template <> to remember that I am specializing a template list, but still there is a template list. Could that be it? I'll try and remove all those template <> tags and see if this has some effect.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Users>[UserName]>Library>Preferences 
Search for "xcode" inside the "Preferences" folder 
Move all the resulting files (I had 6 files when I searched) to Desktop 
Restart your Mac 
Now open Xcode and see if its crashing 
These steps solved my problem. Hope this helps...